# Convert utf-8 into html &...;

Tags: perl

In Perl, how can I convert string containing utf-8 characters to HTML where such characters will be converted into **&...;** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, split on an empty pattern to get a list of single characters. Then, map each character to itself, if it is ASCII, or its code, if it is not:

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

my $utf8_string = "\xE2\x80\x9C\x68\x6F\x6D\x65\xE2\x80\x9D";
my $unicode_string = decode_utf8($utf8_string);

my $html = join q(),
    map { ord > 127 ? "&#" . ord . ";"
                    : $_
        } split //, $unicode_string;
```

Comment: My string contains such utf-8 characters as a multi-char - for example this is hex of the sample: `E2 80 9C 68 6F 6D 65 E2 80 9D`, which represents `“home”`

Comment: My proposed code returns `&#8220;home&#8221;` for this input. Is it what you want?

Comment: No it didn't, but now it does.

Comment: Well, then the string was not utf-8.

Comment: It is UTF-8. It wasn't Unicode code points. Your original code expected Unicode code points.

Comment: OK. I did not expect someone worked with UTF-8 without using the character semantics.

Comment: split / map / join? How about simple s///g?

Comment: is there some reason not to use HTML::Entities?

Comment: @ysth, it's internals boil down to exactly same s///eg, I've mentioned + docs + regexp caching for older Perl + list of readable names for entities.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace every symbol that is not printable and not low ASCII (that is, anything outside \x20 - \x7F region) with simple calculation of its `ord` + necessary HTML entity formatting. Perl regexp have `/e` flag to indicate that replacement should be treated as code.

```
use utf8;
my $str = "testТест"; # This is correct UTF-8 string right in the code
$str =~ s/([^[\x20-\x7F])/"&#" . ord($1) . ";"/eg;
print $str;
# test&#1058;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090;
```